# How do you add an arguement to a sprocket directive in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I am trying to translate the following line into a sprocket directive for an application.js file in rails 4:

```
<script src="vendor/pace.js/pace.js" data-pace-options='{ "target": ".content-wrap", "ghostTime": 1000 }'></script>
```

I know it should be something like:

```
//= require vendor/pace.js/pace
```

but i can't figure out how to add `data-pace-options`.  How do I add it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You will need to configure the `window.paceOptions` as explained in the [official documentation](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/).